# ntopng: How to view rsync traffic

Tags: ntop

I have ntopng installed.  One of my machines is used to rsync data offsite.  When I look at the machine in question, I don't see any traffic flows to the remote server, while I see all of its other traffic.  Wondering if I am either misunderstanding something, or if there's something else I can do.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you shouldn't need to do anything, as `ntop-ng` just shows whatever the collectors receive, and typically the collectors run at Layer 3.

Comment: Are you usin rsync over the rsync protocol directly or over ssh? If you don't know and you use a single `:` as a seperator between host and location, you use ssh, if you use `::` it is the rsync protocol.